# Decode Receipt Swift

Tags: swift, parsing, in-app-purchase, decode, receipt-validation

this is my cide to get the receipt for the in app purchsae as part of my app. It returns to me saying in the logs, "Optional(5107 Bytes)". So there is abviosly a receipt file there but I just wanted to find a few wats to parse/decode this receipt to gain access to the info in those bytes.

The Code(first function in viewDidLoad() so to check the receipt)

```
func checkReceiptFromAppStore() {
    let receipt = self.getReceipt()
    print("receipt Data is: \(receipt)") // prints this: receipt Data is: Optional(5107 bytes)
}

func getReceipt() -> Data? {
    if Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL != nil {
        print("app receipt: \(Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL)")
        do {
            let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!)

            return receiptData
        } catch {
            print("error converting receipt to Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try this: `let receipt = String(data: receipt, encoding: .utf8)`. This will convert your data to readable string (well, it really depends on encoding, but in most cases `.utf8` is ok), Then you can print it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it now returns nil instead of the optional @YuryBogdanov

Answer (score 2):

The receipt is an encoded binary file. The `Data` you get can’t be read and parsed as easily.

Docs: [Locate and Parse the Receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html)

Search for receipt validation on GitHub for examples of implementation.